# Building Python Package with source in different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

When building a python package where the source tree looks like this:

```
src -\
     +- module -\
           <stuff>
     +- setup.py
```

is pretty clear.

Is it possible to build a package where module source doesn't reside in the same location as the setup.py?  For more specific use case the code for the module is either partially or full autogenerated in a location other then `src`

E.g.

```
src -\
     +- setup.py
generated -\
           module -\
                   <module code>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can control the directory where packages reside by using the `package_dir` argument to `setup(...)`

and while it does appear to build a proper source distribution when `package_dir` is a relative path starting with `..`, it appears that `pip` will refuse to install it -- I'd suggest instead nesting your generated code inside that `src` directory instead and then using `package_dir` to select that.

Here's an example which moves *all* modules inside a `generated` subdir:

```py
setup(
    name='mypkg',
    package_dir={'': 'generated'},
    packages=find_packages('generated'),
)
```

Using a setup like:

```
$ tree .
.
├── generated
│   ├── mod1
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── mod2
│       └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

This would make the following succeed after install: `import mod1; import mod2`

If you wanted to make those modules available under a different prefix, you would do:

```py
setup(
    name='mypkg',
    package_dir={'hello': 'generated'},
    packages=[f'hello.{mod}' for mod in find_packages('generated')],
)
```

This would make `import hello.mod1; import hello.mod2` succeed after installation

Comment: This works.  If the generated is at the same level as setup.py.  In my case it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative paths in package lookup configuration. Examples:

#### all distributed sources are in `generated`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    ...
    package_dir={'': '../generated'},
    packages=find_packages(where='../generated'),
)
```

#### selected packages should be included from `generated`

In this example, only packages `spam` and `eggs` from `generated` will be included:

```
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='so',
    package_dir={'spam': '../generated/spam', 'eggs': '../generated/eggs'},
    packages=find_packages(where='../generated'),  # or just ['spam', 'eggs']
)
```

Or implement a dynamic lookup like e.g.

```
package_dir={p.name: p.resolve() for p in pathlib.Path('..', 'generated').iterdir()}
```

#### better implementation by resolving all paths relative to the `setup.py` file

Resolving all paths relative to the `setup.py` script allows you to run the script from any other directory than `src`, e.g. you can run `python src/setup.py bdist_wheel` etc. You may or may not need it, depending on your use case. Nevertheless, the recipe is as usual: resolve all paths to `__file__`, e.g.

```
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


src_base = pathlib.Path(__file__, '..', '..', 'generated').resolve()

setup(
    ...
    package_dir={'': str(src_base)},
    packages=find_packages(where=src_base),
)
```